# Can't install elm-mode using MELPA

Tags: package-repositories

I'm trying to install elm-mode using MELPA. When I try to install it I get an error message:

```
https://melpa.org/packages/dash-20150829.433.el: Not found
```

I can install other things, bu not this.

Comment: How are you trying to install it? You should `M-x` `package-install` RET `elm-mode`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing,

Comment: Could you retry after `M-x package-refresh-contents` ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the old MELPA repository from my `.emacs` file and added this:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Restarted Emacs and it started to work well.